# set an extra property for LinkButton in a repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I have a repeater that has a linked button inside it. I want to get some data in linked button click event. how should I set my extra data and get them in click event? (consider that i want to concat some items in my property)

aspx code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpSliderRest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- ITEM-->
        <div class="span2">
            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                <img src='<%#   Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString().Replace("~", "../..") %>'>
            </div>
            <h6><%# Eval("PrintTemplate_Desc") %></h6>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn1" runat="server" class="btn btn-large btn-block" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                Prperty='<%# string.Format("{0};{1}",Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString(),Eval("PrintTemplate_ID").ToString()) %>'>Select »</asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <!-- ITEM-->
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    string MyProperty=??????????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Attributes` collection.

For example:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    String MyProperty = lbtn.Attributes["PropertyName"];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, It returns null! it even don't add my property to the linkedbutton after rendering the page ( I saw it in fire bug after running project)

Comment: the linked button create below code after running : `<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RWPrintPreview_C_rpSliderActive_ctl01_lbtn1" class="btn btn-large btn-block" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$RWPrintPreview$C$rpSliderActive$ctl01$lbtn1','')">انتخاب »</a>`

Comment: This is strange. I tested it in a simple demo and it works fine, both the server side code and the markup contains the custom attribute. One thought is that the property value contains characters that break the HTML and FireBug cannot see the attribute. Instead of using FireBug view the source directly and check there if the attribute exists.

Comment: Can I ask you to send me your demo? I really don't understand where is the problem..  ,I will apprriciate you :D

Comment: No need to post your email! I will send you a link to download it :)

Comment: Here is the link https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=443F7BF63707662D!14087&authkey=!AD_1n2ce0zK_QQE&ithint=file%2czip. I wrote some comments that explain a few things. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go down the route of using the link button commandArgument property - as that's what it's there for.

So:

```
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn1" runat="server" class="btn btn-large btn-block" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
            CommandArgument='<%# string.Format("{0};{1}",Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString(),Eval("PrintTemplate_ID").ToString()) %>'>Select »</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    string MyProperty= lbtn.CommandArgument;
 }
```